# How can i change the background color of a navigation header menu bar from one color to two colors

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

i am building a website using wordpress and was inquiring how to change the background color of navigation menu from one color to two. i.e one side black and the other side yello

I thought of using a custom image but i feel like it would cause issues with different sizes of screen and browser window size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

background: linear-gradient(to right, black 0%,black 50%,#000000 50%,white 50%,white 100%);